# Docker - Tomcat 8 - Spring Rest 404

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, tomcat8

I m using Spring 4, Servlet 3.1, Tomcat 8 with Docker.
I can deploy and start apps in local then i can access via browser or postman.

The problem is when i deploy inside docker, i m getting 404. I could see the calls are reaching to docker tomcat by checking localhost_access.log but due to some reason i m not getting the proper response.

Here is my docker file, assume the war file name is managementservice.war

```
FROM tomcat:8.0.43-jre8

COPY ./target/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

ENV JAVA_OPTS ""

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

I even tried to deploy as ROOT.war but nothing works here is the docker tomcat access logs

```
172.21.0.1 - - [27/Feb/2019:14:43:34 +0000] "GET /managementservice/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1030
172.21.0.1 - - [27/Feb/2019:14:43:42 +0000] "GET /managementservice/api/v1/ping HTTP/1.1" 404 1052
```

I don't have web.xml, everything is annotation based. i have servlet mapping from /api/v1/*

Comment: Did Tomcat explode the war? Do you have any Tomcat logs like catalina.out?

Comment: Not a solution, but you should strip the rubbish that the default image comes with: `RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*`, and drop the trailing lines in your Dockerfile (the `ENV JAVA_OPTS ""`, `EXPOSE` and `CMD` lines).

Comment: @teppic yeah i have done this and it works perfectly. I don't know why. Thank you very much.